# Call new fragment from view pager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My view pager has 4 fragments.

```
mAdapter = new Adapter_viewPager(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

Here is the code of the adapter:

```
public class Adapter_viewPager extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

            public Adapter_viewPager(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) 
            {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() { 
                return 4;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {

                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new me_fragment();
                case 1:
                   return new myFriends_fragment();
                case 2:
                    return new shareFB_fragment();
                case 3:
                    return new sharePic_FB_layout();

                default:
                    return null;
                }
            }

}
```

Now from fragment 1, I am calling new fragment on some button click. Here is the code for that:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                facebookPictureShareFragment objHomeFrag = new facebookPictureShareFragment();
                 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                 ft.replace(android.R.id.content, objHomeFrag);
                 ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

                 ft.addToBackStack(null);
                 ft.commit();
```

When I click on that button it opens this fragment successfully, but when I press back button, it gives the exception `Recursive entry to executePending Transctions`.

Kindly help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cant embed one fragment into another. Here you are executing one fragment transaction in another one. It's just not allowed. If you want to do so use `getChildFragmentManager()`

```
mAdapter = new Adapter_viewPager(getChildFragmentManager());
mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

See if this is helpful.

Comment: its a fragment where i am calling these code lines ... so getchildFragmentManager() function is undefined error is showing

Comment: @user2064024 try to have latest android support library in your project

Comment: from where can i get that ?

Comment: @user2064024 did u get that?

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```